# current time function returning returning 1970 in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How do i correct my code. I am trying to get the last login time but it keeps returning Jan 1, 1970 12:00 am

This is my code

```
        add_action('wp_login', 'get_current_time', 0, 2);
        function get_current_time($login, $user) {
        $user = get_user_by('login',$login);
        $time =  current_time( 'timestamp' ); or time();
        update_user_meta( $user->ID, '_last_login', $time );
        }

         function return_current_time(){
         $current_login = get_user_meta( $user->ID, '_last_login',  true );
         $the_currentlogin_date = date('M j, Y h:i a',$current_login);
         return $the_currentlogin_date; 


         }
         add_shortcode('lastlogin','return_current_time');
```

Comment: `current_time()` and/or `time()` takes server's time and date. Did you check your server?

Comment: No i did not could that be the issue How can i make it take my website's time

Comment: You should ask the hosting company.

Answer (score 0):

Trying using date() function instead.  This example would get the current date 09-16-2019 and time 6:12:15 for the eastern time zone.

```
add_action('wp_login', 'get_current_time', 0, 2);
        function get_current_time($login, $user) {
        $user = get_user_by('login',$login);

        date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York"); // set your proper timezone

        $time = date("m-d-y h:i:s");

        update_user_meta( $user->ID, '_last_login', $time );
        }

         function return_current_time(){
         $current_login = get_user_meta( $user->ID, '_last_login',  true );
         $the_currentlogin_date = date('M j, Y h:i a',$current_login);
         return $the_currentlogin_date; 


         }
         add_shortcode('lastlogin','return_current_time');
```